# Set column count and horizontal in HorizontalGridView Android

Tags: android, gridview, horizontal-scrolling

I have an issue as I mentioned on the title when I try to create a Grid view that can scroll horizontally by using **android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView**

Result look like that:
[image]

But I need some space between each item and control amount of item appear on screen like this:
[image]

My layout.xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="layout.productListFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/productListGrid"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="top"   
/>
```

I have try to use code below but it's seen to haven't take effect at all

```
android: android:numColumns="3"
android:columnWidth="60dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
```

There is the code of single_product_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/singleProduct_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:src="@drawable/product1" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/singleProduct_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/singleProduct_image"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Tên sản phẩm"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/singpleProduct_ratingBar"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/singleProduct_name"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:numStars="5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/singleProduct_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/singleProduct_image"
        android:layout_below="@+id/singleProduct_name"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="25.000VND"
        android:textColor="@color/mainThemeColor"
        android:textSize="10dp" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this today and for some reason Android Studio (2.3 at the time of this writing) does not show all of the Autocompletion options for `HorizontalGridView` (Leanback v17).

What you are aiming for is:

`android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"`

or you can do it programmatically via

`gridView.setHorizontalSpacing(10)`

where 10 is the spacing in pixels.